# Does there exist a duality between the following two quantum systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, duality

Consider two systems:

A) $N$ number of independent spin $0$ bosons living on a circle.

B) A single spin $0$ boson moving on an $N$-torus.

How do we detect the difference between the two systems mathematically?

In both cases, the RHS of commutators $[X_a,P_b]$ is the same ``i.e. $i\hbar \delta_{ab}$"

Comment: Are your $N$ bosons distinguishable?

Comment: I'd like to consider both cases.